# FTP Reporting Disk Quota Exceeded

Tags: ftp, disk-space-utilization

I am using Notepad++ with FTP_Synchronize to upload files to a server, however, it appears that it is not allowing my file to upload because apparently the "Disk Quota Exceeded"

```
11:18:49 > -> TYPE I
11:18:49 > Response (200): Type set to I
11:18:49 > -> PASV
11:18:49 > Response (227): Entering Passive Mode (*,*,*,*,*,*).
11:18:50 > -> STOR /home/*/../../var/www/html/test.html
11:18:50 > Response (150): Opening BINARY mode data connection for /home/*/../../var/www/html/test.html
11:18:50 > Response (552): Transfer aborted. Disk quota exceeded
```

Now it may appear that yeah my Disk quota is exceeded, however I've gone to the back-end and saw:

```
% Used     Total Usage(MB)    Allocated Quota(MB)
84.71      254.14             300.00
```

**Note**: Stars were put in place for irrelevant data.

Comment: Bandwidth and disk are two different things entirely. The first is how much data you can transfer to and from the server. The second is how much you can store on there. Delete some thing and try again or ask to have your disk quota increased.

Comment: @Oli, good catch. I've posted the correct data now. Mind you, the file I'm uploading is 10KB.

Comment: More information: In FileZilla it's almost as if it tries to upload 3 times. is this normal after failing once?

Comment: I found the solution to my (to me mysterious) disk quota problem here: [Where are all my inodes being used?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/347620/where-are-all-my-inodes-being-used). The quota was the inode quota. Inodes are, I think, pointers to files, where I had reached my maximum number of files, although there was space left on the disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ftp software shows the real-time disk quota information, but the back-end software may not.

Comment: you make a good point, however, the information shown is from the back-end. I don't see how they could get confused.